# How to make PyPI-hosted Ansible plugin discoverable by Ansible

Tags: python, plugins, ansible

I'm writing a lookup plugin for Ansible and would like to deploy it to PyPI, so users would be able to install it with `pip install` and use in their playbooks.

However I do not understand how Ansible is doing the plugin discovery. It's apparently checking `./lookup_plugins` path in the playbook's folder, as well as a couple of fixed paths (one in `~/.ansible`, and another in `usr/share/`). However what I want is to install plugin package into virtualenv.

Is it even possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible (at least as of Ansible 2.3).
*But I'm not a Python expert, maybe there are some workarounds possible.*

Ansible search for lookup plugins in the following locations:

- `lookup_plugins` directory near your playbook file
- `lookup_plugins` directory inside any role that is applied in playbook
- configured lookup plugins directories
  default location: `~/.ansible/plugins/lookup:/usr/share/ansible/plugins/lookup`
  can be overwritten with `lookup_plugins` configuration option or
  with `ANSIBLE_LOOKUP_PLUGINS` environment variable
- `ansible/plugins/lookup` directory inside current ansible python package

So for plugin `mylookup` to be found by Ansible, there should be a file `mylookup.py` in any of the above locations.

If your plugin is very complex to be distributed as a single py-file, you can wrap it into a package plus a separate tiny helper file, so users will have to:

1. `pip install my_super_lookup`
2. Create `~/.ansible/plugins/lookup/easy_name.py`:

   ```
   import my_super_lookup

   LookupModule = my_super_lookup.LookupModule
   ```
3. Use `with_easy_name: ...` or `lookup('easy_name',...)` in playbooks